# How to get Register-Transfer-Language (RTL) Code from C and JAVA Code?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction

When any compiler like GCC compiles a C Program it generates intermediate code. Just like we can get Assembly code by applying -s option to any .c file, similarly I want to get Register-Transfer-Language (RTL) for C and JAVA file . How to get it ?

Comment: Sorry, but i was just searching for any script or any tool for it, but didn't found anything.

Comment: You didn't search very hard: http://calypto.com/en/products/catapult/overview/

Comment: well i tried using Verilog tool and bambu but with no luck.

Comment: It is not nevessary to generate intermediate code.

Comment: Why did you roll back the clarifications that were added to your question? They were not totally unreasonable, and actually clarified your post for those interested in the subject.

Comment: sorry i was unaware that RTL stands for things other than Register Transfer Language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The three adress code is called gimple, see e.g. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html but this seems more frontend-backend communication, it can be dumped using

```
  gcc  -fdump-tree-gimple <file>
```

See  http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~uday/courses/cs324-05/gccProjects/node4.html

from some more IR related dumping options from HLL to deep. Probably you want option 4.

1. **Abstract Syntax Tree (AST).** The -fdump-tree-original-raw switch dumps the textual representation of the AST for given input source.
2. **Gnu SIMPLE representation (GIMPLE)** The -fdump-tree-gimple-raw switch dumps the GIMPLE representation of the input source.
3. **Control Flow Graph (CFG).** The -fdump-tree-cfg-raw switch dumps the CFG form of the GIMPLE code.
4. **Register Transfer Language (RTL IR)** The -da switch dumps the RTL IR of the input source program with the pass number as a part of the dump file name.
5. **Assembly Language (ASM).** The -S switch dumps the target assembly code for the input. In our case, this is the Pentium assembly language.

Comment: thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for. Do we also have such option for java ?  We use javac for compilation in it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done anything with Java, except in coffeecups since I left school 15 years ago.